Are CFA questions on topic?
I enrolled into the CFA program recently and I am going through the different topics.
Some of them are quite basic, and sometimes a matter of convention, however, I was wondering if questions about the CFA material were on-topic, as this exam is for financial professionals?

There are some items that quants might like, like securities valuation and portfolio construction. However, the material is pretty basic, as you've noticed. There's AnalystForum if you want a site dedicated to the CFA. They are to the CFA what QuantNet is to the MFE.

Even in the quant part there is some content that might be interesting I believe...

My understanding was that, especially now, we are looking for high quality quantitative questions. As far as I sympathize with you (currently enrolled for level III in June), I think that CFA is rather weak on the quantitative side, so not a lot of material is going to be really suitable for this site. The FRM/PRM curriculum seems more interesting as far as quantitative material is concerned.
Nevertheless, if you encounter some interesting questions on the way - don't hesitate to put it here. I suppose everyone would be happy to see it. However, I think belonging to the CFA curriculum shouldn't be a reason per se. Normal rules should apply (quantitative, adequate level).
For some easier questions and more exam targeted approach you should indeed check out the AnalystForum. I know a lot of guys are using it for exam preparation.

I absolutely think that it is on topic.  The CFA is a professional certification, so almost by definition it contains material needed by someone working within the site's field.

There are bits of the CFA curriculum that are quanty - Fixed Income Portfolio Management (hedging interest rate risk, OAS pricing, etc.), Quantitative Methods, Derivatives and Swap pricing, and Equity Portfolio Management (Return/Risk attribution). 
I'd say that as long as the question meets the criteria on the FAQ then go for it.
